# 'Can't subset columns that don't exist' for decision trees

Tags: r, dataframe, decision-tree

**Hello, I'm coding a decision tree in R, and there is this error when I run my code :**

Error : Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `Member`, `Normal`, `Normal`, `Member`, `Normal`, etc. don't exist.

**df is a dataframe. Can you help me please ? Thank you. Here's my code:**

````
library(rpart)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(rpart.plot)
library(xlsx)
library(caTools)
library(data.tree)
library(elemstatlearn)

#Loading Excel File
library(readxl)
FINALDATA <- read_excel("Desktop/FINALDATA.xlsm")
View(FINALDATA)
df <- FINALDATA
View(df)

#Selecting the meaningful columns for prediction
df <- select(df, City, df$`Customer type`, df$Gender, df$Quantity, df$Total, df$Date, df$Time, df$Payment, df$Rating)```
````

Comment: You dont' need `df$` inside `select` i.e. `select(mtcars, mtcars$mpg)` returns error. instead it would be `select(mtcars, mpg)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Howerver, when i Write : df <- select(df, City, df$`Customer type`, Gender, Quantity, Total, Date, Time, Payment, Rating) I have the same error =(

Comment: Did I mention that you don't need `df$` i.e. `df$Customer type` should be `Customer type` within backquote

Comment: Here's what it does : df <- select(df, City, Customer type, Gender, Quantity, Total, Date, Time, Payment, Rating)
Errorr : unexpected symbol in "df <- select(df, City, Customer type"

Comment: You could copy/paste the code I provided in the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct usage of `dplyr::select` would be either quoted or unquoted column names and not the value of that column (`df$City` - extracts the value of that column)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- select(df, City, `Customer type`, Gender, 
        Quantity, Total, Date, Time, Payment, Rating)
```

Also, there are many `select-helpers` available (`starts_with`, `ends_with`, `matches`) or use a range i.e. if we are interested in selecting all columns from City to Rating, use the `:`

```
df1 <- select(df, City:Rating)
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!